# Add default params to named route helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have this route

```
get "/articles/:id" => "articles#show", as: :article
```

Which generates the path helper `article_path(article)`.

Is it possible to add some default parameters to this path helper, like `/articles/123?token=123456`? For example I use the `article_path` helper a dozens of times and it would be tedious to always do something like

```
<%= article_path(article, token: article.token) %>
```

I've played around with the defaults of a route, but this does not affect the URL generation, only the `params` object when I'm on this route

```
get "/articles/:id" => "articles#show", as: :article, defaults: { token: "my token" }
```

The only thing I can think of, is to overwrite / monkey patch the helper, but as I need this logic on other helpers too, I was wondering if there is a build in way to do this.

Comment: In short - no. Query string parameters are  transparent to the routes in rails. And the way to do this would be to just write your own helper method which just adds the additional hash argument and calls super.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This logic does not really belong in the routing layer and query string parameters are for the most part completely transparent to the router.

Instead you can just create your own helper method:

```
def article_path(article_or_id, **opts)
  if opts[:token].nil? && article_or_id.respond_to?(:token)
    super(article_or_id, opts.merge(token: article.token))
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! A quick follow up: I'd like to define load the helpers from a class that defines it's own helper module `TokenRoutes.helpers`. How could I load this helper into the view/route helpers?

Comment: The "helpers" are really just a bunch of modules which are included in the controller and the view context. Using a class here does not make sense.

Comment: A class would be something like a decorator where you pass the view context into the initializer to decorate a model instance. There are plenty of tutorials on that.

Comment: `TokenRoutes.helpers` **is** is a module that is generated based on some logic. So the question is, how do I load these helpers so that they override the url helpers? I could put them manually inside the `app/helpers` directory, but then I have to split the logic into two separate places. I also tried to load it in an initializer via `ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) { prepend TokenRoutes.helpers }`. But it seems that the url helpers are created **after** the on_load callback, so they overwrite my helpers, not the other way around.